# How to stub a class method using rspec/rspec-mocks

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, rspec-mocks

I am using rspec-mock for test-driven-development.
I am starting implementing a single class and mocking/stubbing the other classes using rspec-mock. 
Mocking objects of classes yet to be implemented works well.
However when I try to mock a class method of a class that does not exist yet, I haven't been successful.
My class "Hashes" should have a class method "calculate_hashes" receiving a filename and returning a hash.

I tried

```
 allow(Hashes).to receive(:calculate_hash) do |file| 
      # looks up what to return
 end
```

which give the error "Hashes is not a class".
I then implemented a class "Hashes"

```
class Hashes
end
```

and then only tried to stub the class method in the same way.
This gives the error "Hashes does not implement: calculate_hash"
When I then add the method to my class definition:

```
class Hashes
    def self.calculate_hash(filename)
    end
end
```

it finally works and my stubbing of this class method works using "allow(Hashes)" as seen in the example above.
I just wonder if there is a way of accomplishing this without writing this class skeleton.

Or am I maybe trying to accomplish something in an inappropriate way?
Or is rspec-mock maybe not the right tool to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your workflow, I think it's going to work better to use a `class_double` than than to stub the `Hashes` class directly.  `allow(Hashes)` is *always* going to require that the `Hashes` constant is defined.  It's simply how Ruby works and RSpec can't do anything about that.  With a [class double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double), you can instead do this:

```
class_double("Hashes", :calculate_hash => canned_return_value).as_stubbed_const

# or

hashes = class_double("Hashes").as_stubbed_const
allow(hashes).to receive(:calculate_hash) do |file|
  # look up what to return
end
```

`class_double("Hashes")` provides you with a test double that, when the `Hashes` constant is defined, will verify the mocked and stubbed methods against the `Hashes` class definition, but when it is not defined, will act just like a normal double that allows anything to be mocked or stubbed on it.  The `as_stubbed_const` bit tells rspec-mocks to stub the `Hashes` constant for the duration of the example so that any references to `Hashes` get your class double rather than the real `Hashes` class, even if the `Hashes` class has never been defined.

Comment: Ok, that works, thanks! However, I wonder how I would approach an example where I would need a class method and an instance method. e.g. `new_book = Book.new\ content = new_book.read_page(5)`Do I first need to mock the object using `book_object = double("Book")\ allow(book_object).to receive(:read_page).and_return(...)` and then mock the class by `book = class_double("Book")\ allow(book).to receive(:new).and_return(book_object)` Is this the way to go?

Comment: It's hard to read your question due to the comment formatting.  Can you send your question to the RSpec mailing list? groups.google.com/group/rspec