# How to mock the create call for a new ActiveRecord object in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, activerecord, rspec

I have an ActiveRecord object User. In the app I am making I am using a single sign on gem, but I need to save some of the user data in our databse. My ApplicationController has this code:

```
def create_user
  User.create(name: current_user['name'], email: current_user['email'], company_id: current_user['id'])
end
```

I need an RSpec test that mocks out the actual `create` call. I have tried

```
allow_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:create).with(any_args).and_return(user)
```

which returns an error saying "User does not implement create".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jvillian is correct that the problem is that `create` is implemented by `User`, not by an instance of `User`. The simple fix is just to stub the method directly on `User` (i.e. use `allow` instead of `allow_any_instance_of`):

```
allow(User).to receive(:create).with(any_args).and_return(user)
```

Also, `.with(any_args)` is a no-op, so this is equivalent:

```
allow(User).to receive(:create).and_return(user)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking that `allow_any_instance_of` is expecting an *instance* of `User` to implement `create`. `create`, however, is a *class* method. So, I believe the error messages is saying that *instances* of `User` don't implement `create`.

I'd suggest seeing if `class_double` works for your use case. Check out [Rspec Mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848877/how-to-stub-a-class-method-using-rspec-rspec-mocks) SO post from Myron Marston.